# YouTube HTML5 extension for Orbot/Orweb?

Tags: orbot

Is there a HTML5 extension for watching YouTube videos in the new Orweb browser for tablets, like used to be with the Bundle for PCs, all the while offering your computer to the ongoing Tor traffic?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to experience with HTML5 video proxied through Tor, you can try the development builds of our new Firefox-based secure browser, named [Orfox](https://guardianproject.info/builds/Orfox/latest/).

*This is development/debug grade technology and has not been fully tested!*

Answer (score 1):

Support for HTML5 has been removed from Orweb, because it contains security leaks (possible to get users' IPs) - [see here](https://guardianproject.info/2013/08/21/orweb-security-advisory-possible-ip-leakage-with-html5-videoaudio/) . You can use Firefox for Mobile and [ProxyMob](https://guardianproject.info/apps/proxymob/) extension to it.